# Only receiving real time subscription updates for certain users?

Tags: instagram

I've successfully subscribed to a certain tag using the real time API. When I take photos using my account (i.e. the account linked to my developer key), I receive notifications instantly.
However, when a friend uses the same tag I get *no* notification at all. I've checked server logs - there is no request to my subscription url at all.
What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: I received the notifications for my real time subscription several *hours* after the fact.
Anything I can do to speed this up then? I don't need 'real time' to be a matter of seconds, but at least within a few minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Subscription works on push. If that doesn't work, use pull - the frequency is determined by you. Typically, there is a limit of 30 calls/hr. So its about 2 mins per call. You can set up a cron job to pull the media api every 2 minutes : )